# R Return row indicies of sets of duplicates

Tags: r, duplicates

I am curious about how find the row indices of sets of duplicates. Is this possible to do efficiently?

Example of what I am looking for

```
df <- data.frame(state =c( "MA", "MA", "MA", "NY", "CA", "CA", "CA"), 
                 city = c("Boston", "Boston", "Lawrence", "New York", "San Francisco", "San Francisco", "Boston"))
duplicate_sets(df, N=2)
# Should return something like "found duplicates in rows (1, 2), (5, 6)"
```

Comment: Vectors have no concept of rows. Can you clarify your question and give a reproducible example?

Comment: You want to find out duplicates for both the columns or only one?

Comment: Updated to a dataframe if that's distracting. Both columns -- what `duplicated(df)` would return only broken up into sets of duplicates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Up front: finding duplicates can be expensive. This is the methodology `base::duplicated.data.frame` uses to start the process, converting a `data.frame` into a `character` vector of each row, then looking for the duplicates that way. Unfortunately, `duplicated` only returns the second instance (and beyond) of the rows, not including the first instance, so it doesn't meet your need. I don't have the `.Internal(duplicated(...))` code handy, so here's a solution that is close.

Using `table`:

```
df <- data.frame(state =c( "MA", "MA", "MA", "NY", "CA", "CA", "CA"), 
                 city = c("Boston", "Boston", "Lawrence", "New York", "San Francisco", "San Francisco", "Boston"))

duplicate_sets <- function(df) {
  # assuming a data.frame
  xvec <- do.call("paste", c(df, sep = "\r"))
  matches <- Filter(c, table(xvec) > 1)
  lapply(names(matches), function(x) which(xvec == x))
}

duplicate_sets(df)
# [[1]]
# [1] 5 6
# [[2]]
# [1] 1 2
```

It isn't guaranteed to be sorted, but that should be trivial enough for you to expand on your own (if it's even important).

Comment: Thanks, I updated to avoid the rows definition confusion.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit hacky, and the creation of the keys could potentially be inefficient depending on how many columns you have, but this is the type of strategy I like to use for this type of analysis.

I feel like it gives good visibility into what is happening at each step of the way and can easily be refactored for other purposes. This is also fairly easy to wrap up into a function if you ever want to do that.

```
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)

df <- data.frame(state =c( "MA", "MA", "MA", "NY", "CA", "CA", "CA"), 
                 city = c("Boston", "Boston", "Lawrence", "New York", "San Francisco", "San Francisco", "Boston"))



# create a key vector - potentially inefficient depending on your number of columns
df_keys <- sapply(data.frame(t(df), stringsAsFactors = F), paste0, collapse='|')
df$df_keys <- df_keys


# capture original order for use later on
df$original_order <- 1:nrow(df)


# find duplicate keys and create ids for each instance
df_key_dupes <- df_keys[duplicated(df_keys)]
df_key_dupes_id <- 1:length(df_key_dupes)


df_dupe <- data.frame(df_keys = df_key_dupes, df_key_dupes_id, stringsAsFactors = F)


# I use data tables for efficient merges, then back to df
setDT(df); setDT(df_dupe)
df <- merge(x=df, y=df_dupe, by='df_keys', all=T, sort=F)
setDF(df)

# remove NAs which indicate they aren't a dupe
df2 <- df[!is.na(df$df_key_dupes_id),]


# group by the dupe id and paste collapse the original_order field with a comma and space
df2 <- group_by(df2, df_key_dupes_id) %>%
    summarise(dupe_set=paste0(original_order, collapse=', '))  


# print out according to request (sorry, I'm a painfully literal human)
cat("duplicates in rows: ", paste0('(', df2$dupe_set, ') '))
```